# Image with Buttons - just above the Google Map

Tags: android, image, dictionary, android-relativelayout

I'd like to add an image just above My Map with 2 buttons on it. How can I achieve this?
This is what I want to achieve in Android. [image: http://www.machinesthatgobing.com/images/skyhook-iphone-apple.jpg]

Comment: your question is not clear ..what you want ? where you want to add image??

Comment: @ the top ---> In the pic -- Overview(Overview is the image and edit and start are the buttons), I want to add buttons over on this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link :

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/07/draw-on-custom-view-over-mapview.html

Or

You can achieve this by adding a header bar/view something like this ,Use that image as the background of the header view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerlayout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="drawable_image/color(Whatever u want)"
    >

    <Button android:id="@+id/one" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="one">
    </Button>

     <Button android:id="@+id/two" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="two">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>

<MapViewActivity
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="your map key"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will place buttons on a mapview using a RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="your_id" />
    <Button android:layout_below="@+id/mapview"
        android:text="@+id/Button03"
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button android:layout_below="@+id/mapview"
        android:text="@+id/Button02"
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button03"
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```